# Python "Attribute Error" when combining steps

Tags: python, selenium

Hoping someone can help explain the code difference below to a newbie.
Using Python to run Selenium and navigating a page using XPath and click().

## This works:

```
xpath = '//*[@id="blahblah"]'
date = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
date.click()
date.send_keys('todaysdate')
```

## This doesn't work:

```
xpath = '//*[@id="blahblah"]'
date = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
date.send_keys('todaysdate')
```

## Error returned is:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
```

What is the difference between the examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because you're trying to save the return value of `click()` in date. 'click()' does not return anything, aka `None`, so you get an attribute error when you try to call `send_keys` on this NoneType object.

When you want to call multiple functions on an object after creating it, it's best to save it in one variable and call the functions one by one, instead of chaining all of them in one line and making the code a debugging nightmare, not to mention sacrificing readability in some cases.

Still, it's subjective, and there can be situations where chaining together method calls is the way to go (e.g. to save a little memory). However, such situations are few and far between.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I thought the idea of one line was easier to read as functionally the result of the .click() is a click on the xpath element and this moves the cursor on screen to this location for input of "todaysdate".

Comment: Happy to help :). It's tempting to chain function calls like that, but imagine a scenario where one of the calls fails. The error stack trace will only show that one line where you called all the functions, so you won't know which function failed.

Answer (score 3):

Your code would only work, if `date.click()` returned date again. This is not the case (and would be quite unusual). As it stands, `click()` is executed but `None` is returned, so the attempt to send_keys to None fails.

Comment: Okay so when I look at the program output result, the .click() adds the cursor to the xpath location on screen. It is also altering the date as part of the program though....I had missed this